# For loop cumulative calculation problem. C programming

Tags: c

Here I have created a compounding interest calculator. The user inputs principal, interest% and duration (in quarters). I have used a for loop for the initial calculation. But, I don't know how to get the total to rollover to the next quarter's principal.

Say the user inputs 1000, 5% and 2 quarters. The output should look like, Q1 Principal=$1000, Interest=0.05, Total=$1012.50, Q2 =$1012.50 =0.05 =$1025.16

Also my last Do while is giving me some issues. The ouput is spitting out a couple extra lines before letting the user start over.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int a = 0, b=0;
    double interest, prin, total=0;
    char check = ' ';

    do{

        do{

            do{
                printf (" Please enter principal:\n");
                scanf ("%lf", &prin);
            }while(prin <=0);

            do{
                printf ("Please enter desired interest greater 
                        than 0 less than 20 :\n");
                scanf ("%lf", &interest);
            }while(interest <=0 || interest >20);
            interest = interest/100;

            do{
                printf ("For how many quarters would you like 
                        to deposit: (more than 0, less than 40) \n");
                scanf ("%d", &b);
            }while(b <=0 || b >40);

            printf ("Is this information correct? Press X 
                    to continue" );
            scanf ("\n%c", &check);
        }while(check != 'x' && check != 'X');

        total = prin * (1+(interest *.25));

        printf ("Quarter     Principal      Interest      
                Total\n");

        for(a=1;   ;++a){
            printf ("%2d          $%.2f        %.2lf        
                    $%.2lf\n", a, prin, interest, total);
            if(a == b)
                break;
        }

        printf ("Do you want to start over (Y/N)?");
        scanf ("%c\n", &check);
    }while(check != 'y' || check != 'Y');





    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have several levels of loop nesting. Reading such a code without proper indentation is something that sinners will do in the hell.

Comment: This might be .a stupid question, but is there a resource I can find to details on proper indentation?

Comment: If you use any somewhat decent IDE, it can do it for you automatically. There are different styles though that you might want to adopt. Just look around for "indenting C code"... did it for you for now (used gVim).

Comment: Aside: `scanf ("\n%c", &check);` would be better as `scanf (" %c", &check);` that's a space instead of the newline, same thing further down, that space before `%c` is missing.

Comment: Weather Vane. Thank you, that seemed to fix that last do while loop problem I was having.

Comment: one way to achieve appropriate indenting of the code is to 'select' all the code, then click the `{}` button.   In general, indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding: `printf ("Quarter     Principal      Interest    <newline>  
                Total\n");`  Do not break a char string across a newline.   (you can do: `printf ("Quarter     Principal      Interest " <newline> "Total\n" );`  Note that each line has its' own set of double quotes `"`

Comment: the posted code fails to update the principal after every increment by the interest rate.  so the same numbers are always output for every quarter.  This needs correction

Comment: in general, should not mix `int` math with `double` math.  especially all those literal values should be `double` rather than `int`.  You can make them `double`s by appending a decimal point

Answer (score 2):

The are some problem with indentation and logic in your code. You need to updade principle in for loop statement. Then print it out .Here is my solution

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    double interest, prin, total = 0;
    char check = ' ';

    do {

        do {

            do {
                printf(" Please enter principal:\n");
                scanf("%lf", &prin);
            } while (prin <= 0);

            do {
                printf("Please enter desired interest greater  than 0 less than 20 :\n");
                scanf("%lf", &interest);
            } while (interest <= 0 || interest > 20);
            interest = interest / 100;

            do {
                printf("For how many quarters would you like to deposit : (more than 0, less than 40) \n");
                scanf("%d", &b);
            } while (b <= 0 || b > 40);

            printf("Is this information correct? Press X to continue" );
            scanf("\n%c", &check);
        } while (check != 'x' && check != 'X');



        printf("Quarter     Principal      Interest      Total\n");

        for (a = 1; a<=b; ++a) {
            total = prin * (1 + (interest *.25));
            printf("%2d          $%.2f        %.2lf        $%.2lf\n", a, prin, interest, total);
            prin = total;
        }

        printf("Do you want to start over (Y/N)?");
        scanf("%c\n", &check);
    } while (check != 'y' || check != 'Y');
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Loc Trim, Ok so I have assigned "Prin" the value of "total" within the for loop and moved my interest assignment to within the for loop as well.  I have identified the logic errors. Thank you for your help.

Comment: OT: this is bad: `scanf("\n%c", &check);`  and this is bad: `scanf("\n%c", &check);`  Suggest: `scanf(" %c", &check);` and `scanf(" %c", &check);`  Also, when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the return value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful..  Similar to: `if( scanf(" %c", &check) != 1 ) { // handle error and exit }